# Nginx unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock failed

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, magento, nginx, amazon-ec2

I have a magento 2.2.5 application running on two c5.xlarge instance when everything works fine until the heavy traffic load hits on my store. I tried to replicate the issue by putting 500 client for one minute I started getting this issue

> 2018/07/30 09:44:05 [error] 25#25: *1954 connect() to
>   unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily
>   unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.192.10.204,
>   server: MY SERVER NAME IS HERE, request: "GET /products/a-foundations
>   HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host:
>   "MY HOST URL HERE"

I looked into different metrics of load , RAM and CPU I do not see any spike on them they are normal with load 0.6 , RAM 25% and CPU 22% during the test duration.  I am not able to understand what is going wrong with my nginx configuration.

I am using this sample nginx conf : https://github.com/emizentech/magento2/blob/master/nginx.conf.sample